# Performance of multimethod vs cond in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Multimethods are slower than protocols and one should try to use protocols when they can solve the problem, even though using multimethods gives a more flexible solution.
So what is the case with `cond` and multimethod? They can be used to solve the same problem but my guess is that multimethod has a huge performance overhead vs `cond`. If so why would i ever want to use multimethod instead of `cond`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow up on @AlexMiller comment, I tried to benchmark with more randomised data and added up the protocol implementation (also added one more type - Integer - to the different methods).

```
(defprotocol StrConvert
  (to-str [this]))

(extend-protocol StrConvert
  nil
  (to-str [this] "null")
  java.lang.Integer
  (to-str [this] (str this))
  java.lang.String
  (to-str [this] (str "\"" this "\""))
  clojure.lang.Keyword
  (to-str [this] (to-str (name this)))
  java.lang.Object
  (to-str [this] (str this)))
```

`data` contains a sequence of 10000 random integers, that are randomly converted to `String`, `nil`, `keyword` or `vector`.

```
(let [fns [identity            ; as is (integer)
           str                 ; stringify
           (fn [_] nil)        ; nilify
           #(-> % str keyword) ; keywordize
           vector]             ; vectorize
      data (doall (map #(let [f (rand-nth fns)] (f %))
                       (repeatedly 10000 (partial rand-int 1000000))))]
  ;; print a summary of what we have in data
  (println (map (fn [[k v]] [k (count v)]) (group-by class data)))
  ;; multimethods
  (c/quick-bench (dorun (map convert data)))
  ;; cond-itionnal
  (c/quick-bench (dorun (map convert-cond data)))
  ;; protocols
  (c/quick-bench (dorun (map to-str data))))
```

The result is for `data` containing :

```
([clojure.lang.PersistentVector 1999] [clojure.lang.Keyword 1949]
 [java.lang.Integer 2021] [java.lang.String 2069] [nil 1962])
```

- Multimethods:  6.26 ms
- Cond-itionnal: 5.18 ms
- Protocols:     6.04 ms

I would certainly suggest as @DanielCompton : the design matters more than the pure performances that seem on pair for each method, at least on this example.

Answer (score 8):

Multimethods allow for open extension; others can extend your multimethod dispatching on arbitrary expressions by adding new `defmethod`s in their source. Cond expressions are closed to extension by others or even your own code without editing the `cond` source.

If you just want to act on conditional logic then a cond is the way to go. If you're wanting to do more complex dispatching, or apply a function over many types of data with different behaviour then a multimethod is probably more appropriate.

Comment: But how much overhead does multimethod introduce vs cond?

Comment: Agreed. Use whichever approach is best suited to your particular task, and worry about performance later.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "open extension" in this context? It seems to me like cond expressions and multimethods can both be edited/extended, so I don't see why the latter is "open" while the former is not.

Comment: I’ve tweaked this to clarify.

Answer (score 6):

Why worry when you can measure?

Here is a benchmark sample using [criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) library. `Cond` and `Multi-methods` codes are taken from http://blog.8thlight.com/myles-megyesi/2012/04/26/polymorphism-in-clojure.html.

**Caveat** This is just a sample on doing benchmark comparing `multimethod` and `cond` performance. The result below--that shows `cond` performs better than `multimethod`, can not be generalized to various usage in practice. You can use this benchmarking method to your own code.

```
;; cond
(defn convert-cond [data]
   (cond
     (nil? data)
       "null"
     (string? data)
       (str "\"" data "\"")
     (keyword? data)
       (convert-cond (name data))
     :else
     (str data)))


(bench (convert-cond "yolo"))

Evaluation count : 437830380 in 60 samples of 7297173 calls.

             Execution time mean : 134.822430 ns
    Execution time std-deviation : 1.134226 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 133.066750 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 137.077603 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 1.893383 ns

Found 2 outliers in 60 samples (3.3333 %)
    low-severe   2 (3.3333 %)
 Variance from outliers : 1.6389 % Variance is slightly inflated by outliers

;; multimethod
(defmulti convert class)

(defmethod convert clojure.lang.Keyword [data]
  (convert (name data)))

(defmethod convert java.lang.String [data]
   (str "\"" data "\""))

(defmethod convert nil [data]
   "null")

 (defmethod convert :default [data]
   (str data))

(bench (convert "yolo"))
Evaluation count : 340091760 in 60 samples of 5668196 calls.

             Execution time mean : 174.225558 ns
    Execution time std-deviation : 1.824118 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 170.841203 ns ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 177.465794 ns (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 1.893383 ns
nil
```

Comment: You should not trust this benchmark - you are only converting one type, leading to the optimal code path in both cases (monomorphic call site in the multimethod). It's better to test with a randomized mixture of input types (ideally matching the case in your real code).