# What are the benefits of using multimethods instead of cond in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, polymorphism, conditional-statements

Why shouldn't multimethods in Clojure simply be replaced by cond expressions?

I was inspired to ask after looking at the simple examples of multimethods in Ch. 5 of Russ Olsen's book *Getting Clojure*.

In a reply to a similar question ([Performance of multimethod vs cond in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577115/performance-of-multimethod-vs-cond-in-clojure)), user Daniel Compton says

> Multimethods allow for open extension; others can extend your multimethod dispatching on arbitrary expressions. Cond expressions are closed to extension by others or even your own code.

But it's not at all clear to me what "open extension" and "closed to extension" mean in this context, since it seems to me that both multimethods and cond expressions can be edited or expanded quite easily.

So... why shouldn't multimethods in Clojure simply be replaced by cond expressions?

Or, equivalently, how or when exactly can using multimethods be better or more elegant than using cond?

Answer (score 8):

The key point here is "allow for open extension".  Anyone can add new
branches for your multimethods - a `cond` is hard-coded: new dispatches
must be added to the `cond` code in place.

Let's say: you have some widgets and you want to draw them.  The widgets have
a `:type` and you want to dispatch how to `draw` on that type.

Writing a big `cond` for all the widgets **you know about** will work. But now
for each new widget, you have to touch your `cond` source code and modify it.
This *can* be perfectly fine for e.g. an actual application, that does not need
extension.

Doing the same with multimethods, **anyone** can implement a `draw` for their
widget.  So **you** don't know all of them when writing your code.  This makes
it a way better (or even mandatory) approach for e.g. libraries.

Now imagine, that you have decided for the `cond` approach in a library
you are writing.  Anyone with a new widget now must write their own
`draw`, dispatch for their draws first, then call your `draw`.  Also they
would have to make sure, their `draw` is called everywhere, where your
`draw` was called to have it working (which often is just impossible in
a clean way).

One popular example for a multimethod directly in the Clojure core is
[`print-method`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f9b04ae5f7fd9f11ea7a431675f4ec2d23f295f5/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3665-L3667).
By that anyone can implement a "serialization" for their type and play
nicely.

Other honourable mentions for examples to look at are
[clojure.test](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/28efe345d5e995dc152a0286fb0be81443a0d9ac/src/clj/clojure/test.clj)
and [integrant](https://github.com/weavejester/integrant).

Comment: But, in order to extend a multimethod, wouldn't one still need to edit the source code of the multimethod's dispatch function? If so, wouldn't that be just as much work as editing the source code of a cond?

Comment: The `defmulti` decides _how_ to dispatch, and if you want to take part,
your type has to conform _how_ the dispatch is done.  If you have to
change the way, the *dispatch* is done, or have to change the action for
a certain type, then of course you have to touch the original code.
`cond` **decides AND dispatches** while the `defmulti` only extracts the
**how**.

Comment: For a concrete example, suppose that your multimethod's dispatch function is `:type`. I can add a new branch for it without editing the dispatch function: simply `(defmulti foo :mytype ...)`, and then call your multimethod with objects like `{:type :mytype :size 10}`. This is how Clojure's printing facility works.

Comment: I was going to use `print-method` as an example, but you beat me to it!  Doh!

Comment: This follows the [open/closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle): _"software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open for extension, but closed for modification"; that is, such an entity can allow its behaviour to be extended without modifying its source code._