# defmulti vs defmethod what is the difference? In clojure

Tags: functional-programming, clojure

What is the difference between defmethod & defmulti??

Referred to these links. But its still not clear..

1. https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defmulti
2. https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/defmethod

Can someone please help me with the simple example?

Comment: you can think of `defmulti` as a mere signature or abstract method, and `defmethod` as the concrete implementation. You can't call anything defined with `defmulti`, until you provide the defmethod describing behaviour

Comment: ok..this adds up. Then why can't i use defn instead of defmethod?

Comment: you can, but to make the `defn` defined function applicable to different types of vals, like int and sequence, you will have to make some branching code like `(defn add-to [coll something] (if (seq? something) (concat coll something) (conj coll something)))`.. With multimethods you just make the generic function which dispatches on different types of values itself. And what is more important you can add new behaviour without patching existing functions.

Comment: can someone please explain why cant use defn with a simple example is possible?

Comment: @leetwinski that explains things really well. I can now understand why concepts of multi-methods is used. Thank you.

Comment: If you enable JS on the linked sites, you will see lots of examples for those functions. Also check out https://clojure.org/reference/multimethods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are already similar questions on SO - this one in particular I think might be helpful: [What are the benefits of using multimethods instead of cond in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62057461/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-multimethods-instead-of-cond-in-clojure)

Multimethods are one of the mechanisms Clojure provides for implementing *polymorphic* behavior.
Unlike protocols, that only dispatch on the *type* of the first argument of the protocol's functions, multimethods allow for *arbitrary* dispatch via a *dispatch function* that you provide with `defmulti`.

That means `defmulti` defines a new multimethod - its name, docstring, and, in particular, the dispatch function.
But it does *not* define any implementation on its own - it's like an interface with a single method/function.

In contrast, `defmethod` is used to *implement* the multimethod for a particular value returned by the dispatch function.

One important thing to understand is that the dispatch function of `defmulti` takes the *exact same arguments* as the multimethod's implementations.

You can also provide a default implementation that gets called if the value returned by the dispatch function does not match any of the existing implementations. You do this via `(defmethod my-multi-method :default ...)`.

There are numerous examples out there and I recommend you check some of the Clojure books explaining this in detail - e.g. *Programming Clojure, Third edition* dedicates the whole chapter 9 to multimethods.

Joy of Clojure (an excellent and deep book about Clojure in general) also has some good examples, including `compiler` in chapter 9 - I have the examples published here: https://github.com/jumarko/clojure-experiments/blob/develop-performance/src/clojure_experiments/books/joy_of_clojure/ch09_data_and_code.clj#L144-L158
(it also mentions some more complicated concepts like hierarchies - see `derive` - but that is not necessary for you to understand at this time).

Another good example of using multimethods is Clojure itself, e.g. `print-method`. It is defined in clojure.core :https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.11.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3664-L3666

```
(defmulti print-method (fn [x writer]
                         (let [t (get (meta x) :type)]
                           (if (keyword? t) t (class x)))))
```

You can see that this multimethod basically dispatches on the type/class of its first argument.

It is then implemented in numerous places, notably [core_print.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.11.1/src/clj/clojure/core_print.clj).
E.g. for keywords, it's implemented like this:

```
(defmethod print-method clojure.lang.Keyword [o, ^Writer w]
  (.write w (str o)))
```

Another good example is [instant.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.11.1/src/clj/clojure/instant.clj) which provides a few print-method implementations for date-related types.

`print-method` also has [the default implementation](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.11.1/src/clj/clojure/core_print.clj#L87-L90)

```
(defmethod print-method :default [o, ^Writer w]
  (if (instance? clojure.lang.IObj o)
    (print-method (vary-meta o #(dissoc % :type)) w)
    (print-simple o w)))
```

Having print-method defined as a multimethod not only allows Clojure itself to separate implementations for various types but also provides an "open extension" mechanism for the users of the language.
That is you can implement `print-method` for your custom types to print them nicely.
One example of this is the [clj-time library](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time/blob/d9ed4e46c6b42271af69daa1d07a6da2df455fab/src/clj_time/coerce.clj#L122-L125)

```
;; pr and prn support to write edn
(defmethod print-method org.joda.time.DateTime
  [v ^java.io.Writer w]
  (.write w (to-edn v)))
```

Finally, a small tip: `defmulti` uses `defonce` under the hood so to redefine its definition (the dispatch function) while you are working on it, you can use this trick:

```
(def my-multi-method nil)
(defmulti my-multi-method ...)
```

The first `def` will make sure to replace whatever `my-multi-method` points to so you can get the fresh definition without restarting the REPL.